# Will moving questions retain reputation in the originating system?

Tags: discussion, reputation, migration

#### Duplicate:

> [Do migrated questions migrate reputation and badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378).

One of the questions I answered was moved from SO to meta. It was the one answer with the most upvotes I gained. Some were granted after it becoming wiki due to the many answers given, but what about the rest? Will I lose the reputation earned when there is a recalc? And will I gain that reputation on meta when there is a recalc, as it now is wiki?

Not asking because of my ~400 points at stake, just want to know whether this has been taken into account?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378

Comment: Indeed, very duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, did not find it. Vote to close myself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am no quite sure about how it is being handled right now, but I do have an opinion the topic.

Honestly, I think it should make you lose all the rep for the question. Especially if you have enough reputation on the site (maybe >1000?). You should really have read the FAQ by then and you should know which site to post meta stuff on (hint: Not SO.com).

---

#### Edit:

In reply to Jon Skeet's question in the comments, yes I believe this applies to answerers as well. They should know better by now as well.

Comment: @Jon: Wow, beat me to it. That will teach me to be distracted by a dupe comment!

Comment: I agree for the questioner. What about answerers? Should we take a "you should know better" approach on that front too? I think we probably should...

Comment: That is true, put when this was posted, MSO was still faught, maybe not even thought of by Jeff.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, I believe the same thing applies for the answerers.

Comment: @malach: That makes no difference, the FAQ was clear. No subjective or meta on SO.com.

Comment: Subjective is subjective.

Comment: Just to make this clear: I answered and did not ask the question, and the question was tagged sofaq in SO.