# Bug in SO comment system (allows supporting comment twice after question moved)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just supported same comment twice by clicking comment uparrow twice.

Once when question was on Stack Overflow and second time after question was moved to meta.

The question I am talking about is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32897/why-cant-i-subscribe-to-the-stackoverflow-rss-feed-in-opera-10-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer to [this question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/bug-report-migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user)

That question relates to voting on answers, but I guess Jeffs answer would apply to comments as well.