# Hey look I can double down-vote:)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug report: Migrated question’s answers can be upvoted twice by the same user.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/bug-report-migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user)

Not really sure if it's a bug or a feature, but it seemed worth pointing out. If I downvote something on SO, then it gets migrated to SU I can downvote it again on SU with the same account.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/bug-report-migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9414/cant-undo-votes-on-migrated-questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is completely legal... though rather unsporting for the recipient of the downvote.

Comment: True, hence my reporting the problem. I just undid my second down-vote.

Comment: Well, you know what they say - if it was bad the first time...