# I've just found I've been able to vote twice for an answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug report: Migrated question’s answers can be upvoted twice by the same user.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/bug-report-migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user)

It's possible to vote on an answer (and presumably a question) more than once when the question is migrated.

I've just voted on a good [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/111949/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-waking-up-the-cdrom-when-running-explorer/111950#111950) to a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/111949/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-waking-up-the-cdrom-when-running-explorer) which was posted on the wrong site. I then flagged the question to get it moved to the correct site. After the question had been migrated, I noticed that the vote option became available to me again.

My curiosity got the better of me and I tried to vote up the answer again, and indeed, both votes have counted.

I realise that technically, my accounts on the two sites are actually independant, but they have been linked.

Is this by design? or I have I stumbled upon a bug?

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/bug-report-migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user [status-bydesign]

Comment: @fretje: Thanks for that. I did search to make sure it wasn't going to be a dupe. Obviously I didn't search hard enough.