# Migrated question not associated with linked account

Tags: support, questions, migration, linked-accounts

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530838/colour-output-piped-to-less-closed) on Stack Overflow a little while ago that was migrated to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/124846/colour-output-piped-to-less).

When this happened, I went and linked my SO account with SU (and Meta), but my migrated question does not appear to be linked to my account. Is this a limitation or did something go wrong? I'm pretty sure I linked my accounts properly. I'd like to see the migrated question in my profile so I can refer back to it, and, well, because it was my question.

Comment: Interesting. When searching for "mmacaulay" on the Super Users users page you don't show up even though you exist - http://superuser.com/users/32524/mmacaulay. You do appear on SO and SF but not here though (caching?)

Comment: Related to a question of mine http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40199/ive-just-found-ive-been-able-to-vote-twice-for-an-answer-closed

Answer (score 1):

You appear not to have a user name on SU. Try going to your profile on Super User and setting your user name, maybe that fixes things (I have know idea why it should, but maybe it's worth a try).

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the "name" field on my profile page. I just went and changed it. What's weird though is that if you look at that question (on SU), it appears to have been asked by an anonymous user with the name "mmacaulay". I commented on one of the answers after I had linked my account, which appears as the real mmacaulay (and this was before I had added the user name as you suggested)

Comment: @mmacaulay: Hmm, weird. I guess a moderator has to look at this. They'll merge the accounts (whyever they were seperated) and the question will be yours. Just flag the the question for moderator attention and explain what happened.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I've flagged the question on SU for a moderator, with a link back here to explain the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Done.

Disassociated your accounts then reassociated them.

Seems to have called that pigeon home.