# User account association failed to fix lost ownership on migrated question

Tags: support, status-bydesign, migration, linked-accounts, association

Another case of [this migrated-question-not-owned issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45111/migrated-question-not-associated-with-linked-account) cropped up on Super User, so let's file a bug report to see if this is fixable.

Timeline:

- Question [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808239) to SO 05:16z
- Question [migrated](https://superuser.com/questions/139817) to SU 05:22z
- User creates SU account at 18:00z
- User associates SU+SO accounts shortly thereafter
- ***missing:*** migrated question should have transferred ownership here
- User posts [new copy of question](https://superuser.com/questions/140046) at 18:31z

I'll try [@random's workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45111/migrated-question-not-associated-with-linked-account/45226#45226) momentarily, but this process shouldn't require manual intervention.

**Update:** The workaround (disassociating the accounts and re-associating them) doesn't seem to work in this case.  (Maybe it's me?)

Comment: Oh, a Google OpenID. Maybe that's the quirk.

Comment: hmm.  it doesn't seem to be a "standard" Google OpenID, no.  @ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user used Google / GMail on one site, and Google / Google Profiles on the other site.

To us, they look like two different users because the OpenID has nothing in common.

In order for auto-own to work, they have to log in using the same OpenID on both sites.

Comment: but then why did the user association work?