# Question not assigned to linked account

Tags: support, specific-question

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10783/quickly-add-tags-in-flickr/10789) was migrated to Web Applications from Super User, but is not assigned to it's rightful owner, despite him having accounts on both [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/47548/caveatrob) and [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/7510/caveatrob) which are associated with each other.

I can't see the OpenId details on Super User so I don't know whether he's used the same one across all sites, but the Gravatar image is the same.

It appears that he's using different OpenIds on Super User (Google) and Web Applications (Facebook) though the contact e-mail addresses are the same.

This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71519/migrated-question-answer-not-assigned-to-any-user-despite-the-fact-the-account-ex) or [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45111/migrated-question-not-associated-with-linked-account) as both of those appear to have been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been some changes to the way migrated questions are handled which should make this situation rarer in the future.