# Account association for question that is moved to Area-51 Discussions

Tags: support, area-51, migration

I responded to this [question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3166/is-there-a-filmmaker-stack-exchange-group#109595) on Meta, that was later migrated to Area 51 Discussions.
On the Area 51 Discussions page for this question, instead of my user card, there was a gray box with my name (the "anonymous" user card, I guess).
This surprised me, since I have an account on Area 51 and I thought all my accounts were associated with each other. Also, these accounts all use my StackExchange ID and are coupled to the same e-mail address.
I decided to try clearing the account associations and re-associating them, as was suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45111/migrated-question-not-associated-with-linked-account). I got the pop-up asking for confirmation that I really wanted to clear the associations and hit "OK".
However, it looks like nothing has changed. On the [accounts tab of my Area 51 profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/41556?tab=accounts), it still has a button to "clear all associations".
It's been a week since I tried clearing the accounts. Something has apparently gone wrong.

I would like to see my regular user card next to the question on Area 51 Discussions, instead of the gray box.

How do I get the question on Area 51 Discussions associated with my Area 51 account?

Comment: This has now been solved. Thank you SE team!

Comment: @animuson and others: I'm fine with closing this question, as it's no longer an issue. But I think "too localized" would have been more appropriate; the question seems on-topic to me.

Comment: A few months ago, Robert Cartaino posted here about how the A51 Discussion Zone was replacing MSO as the meta site for A51. It seems like someone has been making an effort to find "leftover" A51 questions on MSO to close over the past few days.

Comment: @PopularDemand Thanks for the reply; you are referring to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110547/168333) I think? Seems to me this question does not belong on Area-51 Discussion. It's not about proposals or the proposal process, but about the operation of the SE network - account association, to be precise.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the one. As for this specific question, I believe I did vote "too localized" because the issue was solved but there's no information that could be useful for a future visitor with a similar problem.