# What is the division of labor between MSO and the area51-meta tag on Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, meta-faq

The Meta [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) begins:

> If your question is about:
>
> - Stack Overflow
> - Stack Exchange Area 51
>
> … it is welcome here.

I have asked questions about Area 51 on MSO in the past, but ever since about September, the Area 51 mods have been encouraging posting meta-type questions regarding the site in the `discuss` section using the `area51-meta` tag (which seems to have been in existence since early 2011).

I'm wondering where the dividing line is.  In broad strokes, what sorts of categories of questions are still appropriate to ask, here on Meta, about Area 51?

Comment: I know, this is a Meta-Meta Stack Overflow question.  Have your fun.

Comment: Lightweight. There's no fun until at least [the third meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-meta-meta).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good catch. The meta.SO FAQ is wrong (I requested a fix). Meta.SO is *not* for questions about Area 51.

We are trying to contain questions and discussions about the site creation process completely within Area 51 itself. That means any questions about an individual proposal, the proposal-creation process, and Area 51 should be asked at http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com.

I updated the Area 51 Discussion Zone FAQ to make that clear:

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> The Area 51 Discussion Zone is for users of Area 51 to discuss new proposal ideas, improving or promoting existing proposals, and questions about [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) and the site proposal process. For example,
>
> - Should we merge the _____ and  _____ proposals?
> - Do we really need another site about _____?
> - How do I link to a discussion from the original proposal?
> - What category does the _____ proposal belong in?
>
> ### What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?
>
> You should not ask questions about launched Stack Exchange sites or the operation of the Stack Exchange network (bugs, feature-requests, support, etc). Those questions belong on [our network meta-discussion site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I had noticed 1-2 of the questions on Meta migrating over, so thanks for clarifying.