# Should the area51 tag description be updated?

Tags: discussion, tags, area-51

The [area51](/questions/tagged/area51) tag on MSE stats that

> ... Area 51 has its own [discussion site](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com) which acts as its own meta site.
>  If a question is only related to Area 51, then **it is better** to ask it there.

If someone wants to know now how and why the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) site works the way it does, he / she should *not* ask questions on MSE, since the MSE help center says clearly

> If your question is about:
>
> - Stack Exchange
> - Stack Overflow Careers
> - Promotions & Advertising
> - Support, ... for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers all SE websites
>
> … it is welcome here.

but rather post the content on [discuss.area51](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com) using the [`area51-meta`](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/area51-meta/info) as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110547/298869) answer encourages and the Discussion Zone FAQ mentions:

> The Area 51 Discussion Zone is for users of Area 51 to discuss new proposal ideas, improving or promoting existing proposals, *and questions about Area 51 and the site proposal process.*

So I wonder for consistency, why not change the [area51](/questions/tagged/area51) tag info to something like this:

> ... Area 51 has its own [discussion site](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com) which acts as its own meta site.
>  **This discussion zone is for users of Area 51 to discuss new proposal ideas, improving or promoting existing proposals, *and questions about Area 51 itself and the site proposal process.* This means, if a question is *only* related to Area 51, then it *should be* asked there.**