# Is migration a potential rep Black Hole?

Tags: discussion, reputation, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrated posts lose their pre-migration reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78452/migrated-posts-lose-their-pre-migration-reputation)

Today I asked for (and was granted) migration for a question from SO to Mathematica.SE

When the migration was done I lost some rep on SO, and as I've already capped at the destination site that rep was not gained there. Nothing serious, just a few points.

But I wonder if the same could happen when a heavy voted question or answer (with lots of rep gained over a long time) is migrated. Are all the gained rep over 200 lost forever?

Comment: Wouldn't it also have been lost if the question was asked on Mathematica.SE in the first place?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but often if there is a really high number of upvotes on a question, it will not be migrated anyway. Especially to a lower-activity site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nope. "Over a long time" is the key phrase

Comment: True, I think that migration reputation should not be capped, same way like bounty - the system should transfer the same amount of reputation gained on the original site to the new site.

Comment: According to [this answer by an SE developer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78452/migrated-posts-lose-their-pre-migration-reputation/88066#88066) (and especially in the comments below the answer), you should gain the same amount of rep on the destination site as you gained on the source site.  This comment, especially, seems to indicate that: "*...the votes maintain their creation time when migrated...the rep you have on the initial site effectively transfers over*"

Comment: @jadarnel27 Yep. I rechecked and the rep is there, with the correct date. My bad. Please post that as an answer.

Comment: BTW this is a dup of that q (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78452/migrated-posts-lose-their-pre-migration-reputation/88066#88066)

Comment: Voted to close //

Comment: I'll just to vote to close as well.  No need to post another answer, when it's answered in the other post =)  Glad I could help!

Comment: @jadarnel27 Yep. Thanks a lot! I made a few searches and couldn't find it.

Comment: Vote migration is strange in many ways. This one seems to be one of the harmlesser ways.