# What happens to rep earned on posts that are later migrated?

Tags: support, reputation, migration

I had a [question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8921/is-a-new-area-51-site-under-development) that was migrated to Area 51 on 23<sup>rd</sup> January, after receiving 3 upvotes here. However, I suddenly lost the 15 rep from the upvotes today(almost a month later).

[image]

If I understand this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88066/200868) correctly, then that is not supposed to happen and rep gained on the original site is to be retained on the original site. Is this correct ?

What happened to my rep ?

Comment: That answer's outdated, part of the reason we can no longer migrate after 60 days is so you can't keep rep (since you keep rep on old, upvoted posts after deletion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Migration stubs (the piece left on the original site after migration) get [deleted after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79082/158667).

Once that happens, you lose the associated rep on the source site, as stated in the answer you linked to.

[Your question stub](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164745/is-a-new-area-51-site-under-development?noredirect=1) was deleted about an hour ago.

Comment: Thanks. The link to the question on MSO still redirects to the migrated post on Area 51 (without the `noredirect=1` option). If the stub were deleted, shouldn't it stop redirecting ?

Comment: Why should it? Better like that isn't it?

Comment: Do we get reputation for the upvotes already present in the site where the question got migrated?

Comment: @AsheeshR migrated questions have links to where they were migrated. So when clicking a link which links to a question which has been migrated, the user is taken to the new site where the question was migrated.