# Double voting with question that have been migrated

Tags: bug, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrated question's answers can be upvoted twice by the same user.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user)

I have upvoted this [awesome question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81441/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor?noredirect=1) before it got migrated to [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor). The thing is that once it got migrated I could upvote it again on stackapps.

This question was really worth 2 upvotes, but normally I shouldn't be able to upvote it twice.