# Should I be able to vote again on a migrated question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, up-votes, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrated question's answers can be upvoted twice by the same user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user)

A [question from Bricks](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/how-to-best-photograph-lego-blocks) has just been migrated to Photography, where I have a linked account.

I had previously voted on the question and both answers when it was on Bricks, and now it is on Photography I am able to vote all over again.

Whilst this is clearly great for the users involved, is it correct behaviour?

Bear in mind that the users who answered reached their rep cap of 200, and are now seeing that they are capped out at around 145 (5 upvotes at time of move).

Comment: Apologies, I did search first, and checked the suggestions while writing it, but I still missed that :S