# Are my votes carried over when a question is migrated to a site where I can't vote?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, migration, privileges

On Foo.SE, I have voted up a question and down one of its answers. After this, moderators decide it's best to migrate this question to Bar.SE. However, I don't have enough rep for voting privileges on Bar.SE. **Are my votes carried over to Bar.SE even if I don't have enough rep to vote there?** What if I have enough Bar.SE rep to vote up but not down?

Comment: Related: [What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).  Most of your questions should be answered there either directly or indirectly.

Comment: @psubsee2003 kidna? Like, now I know downvotes on the _question_ are cleared, but I don't know about upvotes, downvotes on answers, or how privileges affect these.

Comment: Votes *do* migrate.

Comment: *It preserves the current revision of the question, all its answers, and any comments on any of those posts, **as well as most of the votes.*** - so that  does answer the vote question, the upvotes are carried over.

Comment: Votes do *not* migrate. Vote *totals* migrate. See, e.g., http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20208/ for when the distinction matters. I sorta feel this ought to be a duplicate of something in the linked/related questions on there, but it looks like it's always been a [tag:feature-request] to fix the double-vote, never a [tag:discussion] like this. Though maybe this has changed since then?

Comment: As far as I know, all votes are migrated, but owned by Community account: if you have account on Bar.SE with enough rep you can vote again, since your first vote is not yours anymore. However, not 100% sure of this hence just a comment.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, you can vote again with each migration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On migration, [votes are preserved if the question has a positive score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/162102).  However, the *ownership* of those votes is not preserved; the votes are transferred to the Community user at the time of migration.  If you voted on the original site (and have the reputation to do so), you can also vote on the destination site.  So yes, migration allows double-upvoting.  (This also means you can't cancel your vote post-migration, because it's not your vote any more.)  Clearing migration history doesn't change any of this.

It would be better if [all votes were cleared on migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87031/162102); that users on Community A thought it was a good question doesn't mean that it's a good fit for Community B.  The question should get a fresh start on the new site, and then you wouldn't have any concerns about double-voting.  But that's not how it works now.

Comment: I wonder if the votes are cleared on clearing the migration history.

Comment: @BhargavRao that's an interesting question.  Science time?

Comment: Yep, definitely need to figure it out.

Comment: Migration history does nothing to votes; votes are established *by the originating site* at the time of migration; which are preserved and which are lost is set in stone at that time and unaffected by later events on the destination site.