# Can Chat allow POST requests from all origins?

Tags: feature-request, javascript, chat

In chat, I can read events by sending a `POST` request to this URL:

```
http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/chats/roomID/events
```

However, there seems to be a Same Origin Policy, preventing CORS. Could it be changed to allow it from everywhere?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This would make many things easier for us.

Comment: Seems you didn't figure out a way! :P (I couldn't either :/) +1 :)

Comment: Nope :( So this might be the only way

Comment: hmmm... [I've now upvoted you twice!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20208/260841) ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the purpose of this... requests to that URL must include the `fkey` parameter, which is obtained directly from one of the chat pages. How would you be able to obtain this parameter?

Comment: @uɐɯsOuɐɥʇɐN In chat, go to javascript console and enter `fkey().fkey`