# Able to upvote migrated questions twice

Tags: bug, status-declined, voting, migration

Got a weird (or neat) bug here.  [This question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/40954/draw-music-in-software?newreg=0156cc52d5f24124ba0bfe398ad00adc) was migrated from music.SE to sound design beta.  I happen to remember that I upvoted if not all, all but one of the other answers on the question.  However, since it has been migrated to sound.SE, *although the answers preserved their votes from music.SE*, I am able to upvote them *again*.

I remember, for instance, that I was the only one to have upvote the accepted answer.  My upvote is still there, but I can upvote it *again*, giving me a double-vote power.

Not a critical bug, but still a bug that could use working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, but for such an edge case, we are OK living with it.