# Voting a second time on a post after migration

Tags: support, bug, voting, migration

Yesterday I was reading a question on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) which I upvoted. While I still had that question open in my browser it was migrated to here. I instantly switched to the migrated question which at that time had as much votes as it had on MSO. I noticed however that there was no more indication that I have voted. So out of curiosity I clicked the upvote button again and to my surprise this *did* result in an upvote wich allowed me to effectively vote twice on one post. Is this intentional?

Comment: This was previously filed as a bug, but marked as by design: [Migrated question's answers can be upvoted twice by the same user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user)

Comment: I might add that while that bug is from 2009, the [same issue was brought up again in 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291027/able-to-upvote-migrated-questions-twice) and the team arrived at the same decision.