# How do migrated questions get counted, for site statistics?

Tags: support, migration, site-stats

This is really just a matter of curiosity.  When a question gets migrated to another site, where does it end up being counted for site statistics?  Does it only get counted where it was originally posted, or on the receiving site, or both?

To be more clear, I'm wanting to know how the questions affect the site's usage statistics, like questions per day and such.

Comment: @JonSeigel - Question/Answer rates, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6378/154443)** says that votes and rep get transferred.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is more about site-wide statistics.  I'll try to clarify.