# If I post a reply and the question gets migrated, what account gets the reputation change?

Tags: support, reputation, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do migrated questions migrate reputation and badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges)

I posted a reply to a question that got migrated to a site I don't have an account with. My answer was accepted as right but I don't see any reputation change?

Comment: That doesn't cover what happens when it gets moved to a site which the user doesn't have an account with.

Comment: Now it does. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an account on the new site - using the same OpenID as your existing accounts so that they get associated properly - your new account will get the reputation from any up-votes or acceptances.

In the meantime the reputation is held in "limbo" and not assigned to any account.

Comment: is there an ammount of time it is held in limbo for?

Comment: @Celeritas - As far as I know there's no time limit. But what's stopping you just creating an account?

Comment: I don't think I'd ever use it.

Comment: @Celeritas then why do you care whether the rep gets credited to the anonymous account that was created for you?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Obviously I'd prefer the rep to go to an account I have, ideally the one I replied with.

Comment: Rep is only valid on the site where the question exists. If the question gets migrated, the rep goes with it, whether you decide to follow it or not.