# reputation for migrated question

Tags: support, reputation, migrated-questions

If my question is migrated to other site ,
for example , Question-A from Site-A is migrated to Site-B .
If this question is Up-voted in Site-B , what site of user's reputation will be increased ?
Site-A or Site-B ?

Comment: Site-B, for votes after the migration.

Comment: Will this question be deleted in Site-A ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges

Comment: Eventually, I'd imagine. Probably an automatic process.

Comment: @Juhana - The linked question is for answers. this question is for questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question-A from Site-A is migrated to Site-B . If this question is
>   Up-voted in Site-B , what site of user's reputation will be increased
>   ?

When your question is migrated from Site-A it is actually removed from site-A so that means that question is no longer a part of that site because of which it can not have upvotes or downvotes.

Therefore if the question is upvoted in Site-B it will not have effect in your reputation on Site-A

> what site of user's reputation will be increased ? Site-A or Site-B ?

As your question is now on site-B the reputation changes for upvotes and downvotes will only be effective for Site-B and not for Site-A where the question was actually asked.

**EDIT :**
As informed by @ Sha Wiz Dow Ard ,
The question is not removed instantly. It's locked for 30 days and only then deleted (by an automatic process). 
The reasoning behind this is to give the target site time to reject the migration (by closing it) then it's rebounded back.

Comment: It's not removed instantly. It's locked for 30 days and only then deleted (by an automatic process). The reasoning behind this is to give the target site time to reject the migration (by closing it) then it's rebounded back.

Comment: ok thanks for information @ShaWizDowArd let me add it to my answer

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard , if it's rebounded back within 30 days , will the question be unlocked ?

Comment: @zey yes indeed, and I believe there's even "migration rejected" message in the revisions.