# Where does my question get posted if it gets migrated?

Tags: support, migration, views, migrated-questions

If my question gets migrated or I flag it to be migrated, then where does it get posted? What is its status? Is it shown as a new question? Is it at the top of the list?  Are the chances of people seeing it any more or less than a question originally posted on the same site?

Comment: Additional information about: [answers, reputation and badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6378/282094) of migrated questions.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's shown as a [new question on top of the homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/295232) (of the site it's migrated to). It appears to be asked at the time it was migrated, though on the question page itself there will be a link to the question at its original location where you can *really* see how old it is.

Migration does not have a large effect on how many people see it on the new site, but here are some thoughts:

- For a while, it will be on the homepage of two sites (if it's migrated while still on the homepage of the original site).
- Upvotes from the original site are carried over, so if it had a positive score and users are more likely to click on questions with a positive score, that might have an effect.

  - It might attract slightly more upvotes this way, and if you're lucky it might hit the Hot Network Questions list because of this, but those are all secondary effects.
- Migrated questions are listed in the [moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) but hardly anybody looks at those.